# How to revert editor background color after search in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My end goal is to have ABSOLUTELY NO HIGHLIGHTING on any text after I click away from it.  As you can see, the background of previously selected text does NOT revert after a Replace operation.  I've looked for days and continue to find discussions relating to the "inactive selected text," but this does not seem to be the correct area.

Here's a look.  Keep in mind that nothing is actually selected here:

[image: Dark Theme]
[image: Light Theme]

Answer (score -1):

I have Visual Studio Express, and in it when you click away from a search and replace or find, the actual search window doesn't close automatically and the highlighting remains there. If I want the highlighting to go away, and when I'm done with the search and replace, I just close the search window. It is not actually a window, but here is what it looks like on mine:

[image]

When I close this window, or dialog box or whatever, the highlighting goes away as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I just tried closing the window and it did not work.  =(

Comment: hmmm, sorry, but can't think of anything right now. I don't have reshaper though, or for that matter any other plug-ins (because it is the express version).